# error de rutas con angular 11 cuando hago build en donweb (hosting compartido)

Tags: angular, hosting, build, angular11

estoy armando un sitio para un amigo en angular 11 y cuando ingreso a las rutas directamente, por ejemplo : http://c1970754.ferozo.com/servicios
como lo llamo en **app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {path:'servicios', component:SectorVentasComponent},
```

me da error 404, esto no sucede cuando estoy navegando.
aun así cuando estoy navegando no puedo acceder a esta ruta
http://c1970754.ferozo.com/servicios/alarmas
como lo llamo en **app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {path:'servicios/:itemNombre', component:ItemComponent}
```

entiendo que haya otra ruta con servicios no me debería generar problemas.
también buscando en Internet probé lo siguiente cuando ejecutaba el build y nada

```
ng build --prod --base-href=""
```

```
ng build --prod --base-href="/"
```

```
ng build --prod --base-href="./"
```

cual seria el problema ?

aclaro que esto en local no pasa.

*para los que accedan en un futuro quizás las url no funcionen*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que por lo que veo te esta faltando setear las reglas del htaccess. Ya que al ser una single page aplication necesitamos decirle a el servidor que todo se resulve en index.html

algo asi tal vez te puede servir

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Tambien en soporte tecnico, ya que cada empresa de alojamiento web tiene sus reglas puedan ayudarte

aquí ademas hay un auto generador de htaccess https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator